# How to solve navigation.navigate error when set TouchableOpacity in StackScreen header options?

Tags: react-native, navigation, stack-navigator

I want to add a button(icon) on stack header(on right side). On-click it goes to that page but it's not working. It appears 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')'.

Below is my code:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="Page1" component={Page1} />
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Page2"
    component={Page2}
    options={{
      headerRight: () => (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Page3')}>
            <Image source={require('../assets/image.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )
    }}
  />
  <Stack.Screen name="Page4" component={Page4} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Page5" component={Page5} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the navigation from the options to the headerRight:

```
options={({navigation}) => ({
         headerRight: () => (
          ...
         ),
      })}
```

or useNavigation():

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

EDIT 2:

fixed your snack code and its working fine:
You had to add a stackScreen called 'MyorderStack' because you're trying to navigate to that.

```
<NavigationContainer independent={true}>
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerTintColor: 'blue' }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Global Page" component={AppNavigator} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    <Stack.Screen name="DetailOne" component={DetailOne} options={({navigation}) => ({ headerBackTitleVisible: false, title: 'Global Page',
      headerRight: () => (
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',justifyContent: 'flex-end',width: '50%'}}>
          <View style={{ marginRight: 10 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MyorderStack')}>
              <Image source={require('./assets/shop.png')} style={styles.Image} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
       ), headerTitleAlign:'center', headerTintColor:colors.primary
      })}
    />
    <Stack.Screen name="DetailTwo" component={DetailTwo} options={{headerBackTitleVisible: false, headerTitleAlign: 'center', title: 'Global Page', headerTintColor: colors.primary}} />
    <Stack.Screen name="MyorderStack" component={MyorderStack} options={{headerBackTitleVisible: false, headerTitleAlign: 'center', title: 'Global Page', headerTintColor: colors.primary}} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: not working. here is full working expo link. help please. https://snack.expo.dev/@john.ocean/global-mobile-dummy

Comment: you're using navigation in both App({navigation}) and headerRight in this link. Just use one of them or under App, before the render, add const navigation = useNavigation() and remove {navigation} from App and headerRight.

Comment: I tried it but it's not working. :(

Comment: Can you show me how you're doing it now? (update the expo snack to the current version that is not working)

Comment: I tried (1. removed navigation from App({navigation}), 2. removed navigation from header) & also also added const navigation = useNavigation()..

Right now navigation is in header.. you can check it.

Comment: navigation.navigate('MyorderStack') you don't have a screen called MyOrderStack. Add a stack screen called MyOrderStack that takes MyOrderStack as a component. This would allow you to navigate to the other stack.

Comment: Already have screen named MyorderStack in it

Comment: @JohnOcean edited my answer. You need to pass navigation from options not headerRight. Let me know if this works for you

Comment: sir, it still not working.. :(

Comment: @JohnOcean check the latest edit. Tried it on your expo snack and on my device and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

`Navigation` is only defined within the screen's components. In your case, you can try `useNavigation` hook to navigate to different screen. Import it like:

```js
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

and declare it like:

```js
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

Then you it to your `TouchableOpacity` prop like `onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Page3')}`.

Hope this works for you. Thanks

Comment: Tried it but not working :(. Here is full expo link. Please help. https://snack.expo.dev/@john.ocean/global-mobile-dummy

Comment: Remove the `navigation` prop which you're using here `function AppNavigator({ navigation, route })` and use the `navigation` only with useNavigation().

Comment: sorry sir, I tried it but it's not working.